# Incompatible return type on derived query in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following Spring project and trying to use the derived query to return one Bird by Id.

**Bird**

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Bird {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    @NotEmpty(message = "Name must not be null or empty")
    private String name;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Sex sex;

    // other stuff
    }
```

**BirdRepository**

```
public interface BirdRepository extends JpaRepository<Bird, Long> {

    Bird findById(Long Id);
}
```

**BirdServiceImpl**

```
@Service
@Transactional
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BirdServiceImpl implements BirdService {

    private final BirdRepository birdRepository;

    @Override
    public Bird get(Long id) {
        return birdRepository.findById(id);
    }
}
```

**BirdService**

```
public interface BirdService {

Bird get(Long id);
}
```

The error I get in the IDE is:

```
`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'birdRepository' 
defined in com.nz.eagle.repository.BirdRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on
JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract com.nz.eagle.model.Bird   
com.nz.eagle.repository.BirdRepository.FindById(java.lang.Long)! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.nz.eagle.model.Bird     
com.nz.eagle.repository.BirdRepository.FindById(java.lang.Long)! No property 'findById' found for type 'Bird'!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.nz.eagle.model.Bird     
com.nz.eagle.repository.BirdRepository.FindById(java.lang.Long)! No property 'findById' found for type 'Bird'!`
```

**Q:** What am I missing. I want to be able to use the derived Save and Get methods for one entity.

Comment: How does the Bird class look?

Comment: Add entity. Would you mind updating your answer (would also be great to see the dervied save method)

Comment: Try to autowire this birdRepo that you are using in serviceimpl

Comment: Why can't you use the `Optional<T> findById(ID primaryKey);` provided from the CrudRepository?

Comment: I guess the problem lies in that the query can not guarantee to return a Bird. You can unwrap the optional in your service layer by defaulting to null, if you really want to. (I'd stick with the optional).

Comment: I am using Optional<T> findById(ID primaryKey); aren't I? Do I need to add the Crud repo or does it come with JPA?

Comment: 1. Bird entity must have a no-args constructor. 2. Remove the Bird findById method from BirdRepository and just use the auto-generated one in your service like: return birdRepository.findById(id).get()

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, you can try the following steps:

1. Make sure the Bird entity class has a property named id of type Long and that it is annotated with the appropriate annotations, such as `@Id` and `@GeneratedValue`.
2. Verify that the Bird entity class is correctly mapped to the database table. Ensure that the table has a primary key column matching the id property of the Bird entity.

To properly find the error I need the `Bird.class` enitiy definition.